# hls.js currentTime not working how to start video from x seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, hls.js

i've been trying to make a html5 player to play m3u8 files but i want to start from x seconds but its not working.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
  
     <video id="video" width="100%"  autoplay height="100%" controls class="player">
     <track src="subtitles" label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" default>
     </video>
     <script>
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var startTime = 55;
if(Hls.isSupported()) {
  
  var hls = new Hls();
  hls.loadSource('https://vz-f68ee764-984.b-cdn.net/73e38955-bf02-4129-84b8-981f596a5fe0/3840x2160/video.m3u8');
  hls.attachMedia(video);
   hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function()
        {
 video.play();
 video.currentTime = startTime;
   });
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start the video from a specific time you can put in the config object:\

```
const config = {
 startPosition: 10 // can be any number you want
}

const HLS = new Hls(config);
```

Check this link: [HLS.js doc](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#fine-tuning)
And also: [this one](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#startposition)

There is another way to do that: